# Mysql fulltext search relevance

Tags: mysql, search

The query bellow:

```
select tag, MATCH(t.tag) AGAINST ('cartofi copti la cuptor') as relevance
FROM tags t
WHERE MATCH(t.tag) AGAINST ('cartofi copti la cuptor')
```

The results is:

```
1) Cartofi la cuptor cartofi copti la cuptor - 8.298574447631836
2) Cartofi copti - 6.979184150695801
3) Ardei copti umpluti cu branza snitel de ardei copti - 6.61628532409668
4) Cartofi la cuptor cu sos de carne cartofi cu pui la cuptor - 5.385213851928711
```

My question is why 3) is before 4) ? The 4) contains 2 match keywords and 3) contains only one keyword.

The t.tag field is a text field with fulltext index. The table engine is MyIsam of course.

Mysql version is 5.5.20-log

Comment: isn't its because you have 3 first & 4 later in your DB row??

Comment: you are saying that the row location in the table matters?

Comment: maybe.... what you say??

Comment: Nope. i've changed the locations in the table and no change.

Comment: Have you set FT_MIN_WORD_LEN to less than the default 4 characters? MySQL FULLTEXT ignores words less than 4 characters in length unless you state otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to rebuild your index.

Comment: As far as i know the match in mysql is case insensitive so the capital letter does not matter (also tested with and without and the relevance value is the same)

Comment: @keepwalking Both cases have two keywords. Did you see?

Comment: Also the 4) contains 4 keywords. 2 cuptor and 2 cartofi

Comment: No. I see that 3) has same keywords twice and 4) has 2 different keywords twice (4 in total)

Comment: with la there are 6 in total for 4). Take a look closer: cartofi, cuptor and la. each twice. But 'la' does not matter. Min word is 3.

Comment: @keepwalking Try to rebuild your index